# youtube video sharing on facebook wall using facebook graph API in ios

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api, ios5

I am trying to share youtube video on facebook wall using facebook graph API but its not getting share on FB wall, I have got notification from facebook :"Your video could not be processed.Visit the video help page to learn about common problems."  I have used following code.

`

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   receivedData, @"video.mov",
                                   @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                                   strMessage, @"title",
                                   @"", @"description",
                                   nil];

    NSLog(@"video data is..%@",params);

    [appDel.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/link"
                                andParams:params
                            andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                              andDelegate:self];
```

`

Then I have tried to share youtube link and thumbnail image, in this case link is getting share on facebook wall but thumbnail image not getting posted on wall even i tried to send static image also but no luck. for this I have used following code.

`

```
  //       NSString *imgnam=[self->arr_Thumnail objectAtIndex:indexForThumnail];
  //          id path = imgnam;
  //                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
  //                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
  //                UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];




    NSString *image_link = @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/#####/2.jpg";

    NSString *videoLinkString=[self.arr_http objectAtIndex:indexForVideoBtn];

   // NSLog(@"imageString..... %@ ",thumnailImg);
    NSLog(@"videoLinkString..... %@ ",videoLinkString);

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"274849509266872", @"app_id",
                                   @"http://youtube.com", @"source",
                                   image_link, @"picture",
                                   videoLinkString, @"link",
                                   strMessage,@"message",
                                   nil];


    [appDel.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate: self];
```

`

Any idea or help how to share youtube video with thumbnail on facebook wall using facebook graph API, would be greatly appreciated.